# How to support user-chosen font size in UITableView section headers in iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, ios7

I've got an iOS app where I want to support the user-chosen font sizes (`preferredFontForTextStyle`).  Most of my content is in table views.

It seems that the default `UITableViewCell` labels don't automatically change their font sizes.  This is somewhat annoying, but is solveable; I just set the font size on them myself in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  But how do I do it for the section headers?  Right now I'm just returning a string title from `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` in my data source.  Am I going to have to use `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` instead and build up my own view, manually imitating the default header style?  That *can't* be right.

I know the headers are supposed to change, because all the table view content in the Contacts app changes its font size when you change the system font size setting.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setFont:[UIFont preferredFontForTextStyle:UIFontTextStyleHeadline]];
[[UILabel appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UITableViewHeaderFooterView class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5f alpha:1.0f]];
```

Comment: Will the header view itself grow as needed with the larger font size?

Comment: no, you still need `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection`, but at least you wont build your own view in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection` anymore.